Green Function Expansion Theorem Proof
Let $G(t,\tau,l)$ be the Green Function associated to a differential self-adjoint eigenvalue problem:
$$
\hat{L} \psi = l \psi \hspace{2mm} \text{on} \hspace{2mm} [a,b] \\
\underline{\hat{U}} \psi = \underline{0} 
$$
where $\hat{L}$ is the differential operator and $\underline{\hat{U}}$ is the boundary condition vector operator. If $\{\chi_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ is an orthonormal basis of eigenfunctions of the problem in $\mathcal{L}^2([a,b])$ and if the corresponding sequence of eigenvalues is $\{\lambda_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ then I would like to prove that:
$$
G(t,\tau,l) = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{\chi^*_k(\tau) \chi_k(t)}{\lambda_k-l}. \hspace{3mm} (t,\tau,l) \in [a,b] \times [a,b] \times (\mathbb{C}-\sigma)
$$
where $\sigma$ is the spectrum of the problem (notice that we may need to impose $t\neq\tau$ when the order of $\hat{L}$ is $1$ because in that case $G$ is discontinuous along $t=\tau$). Moreover, I would like to prove that for fixed $(t,\tau)$ the convergence is "normal" (i.e. locally total) in $l$, so that I can study the analytic properties of $G$ using the series.
Can someone point me towards a proof or a reference for this result?

Let me know if I can explain myself more clearly.
